# Android Google Maps v2 ReadWriteDirectByteBuffer Exception

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I normally don't get this error but it occurred a few times while loading the map.

Below is my stacktrace and java code

Here's the stacktrace:

```
E/MAP(23027): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/MAP(23027):   at java.nio.ReadWriteDirectByteBuffer.put(ReadWriteDirectByteBuffer.java:137)
E/MAP(23027):   at java.nio.ShortToByteBufferAdapter.put(ShortToByteBufferAdapter.java:160)
12-26 17:53:57.519: E/MAP(23027):   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.c.a.d.d(Unknown Source)
12-26 17:53:57.519: E/MAP(23027):   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.c.a.d.a(Unknown Source)
12-26 17:53:57.519: E/MAP(23027):   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.a.a(Unknown Source)12-26 17:53:57.519: E/MAP(23027):     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.c.b(Unknown Source)
12-26 17:53:57.519: E/MAP(23027):   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.c.a(Unknown Source)
12-26 17:53:57.519: E/MAP(23027):   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.l.a(Unknown Source)
12-26 17:53:57.519: E/MAP(23027):   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.l.b(Unknown Source)
12-26 17:53:57.519: E/MAP(23027):   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.dc.k(Unknown Source)
12-26 17:53:57.519: E/MAP(23027):   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.dc.run(Unknown Source)
12-26 17:53:57.531: E/AndroidRuntime(23027): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 4935
12-26 17:53:57.531: E/AndroidRuntime(23027): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 17:53:57.531: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at java.nio.ReadWriteDirectByteBuffer.put(ReadWriteDirectByteBuffer.java:137)
12-26 17:53:57.531: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at java.nio.ShortToByteBufferAdapter.put(ShortToByteBufferAdapter.java:160)
12-26 17:53:57.531: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.c.a.d.d(Unknown Source)
12-26 17:53:57.531: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.c.a.d.a(Unknown Source)
12-26 17:53:57.531: E/AndroidRuntime(23027):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.o.a.a(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my java code :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if(isGooglePlay()){
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_meter);



        // Get handles to the UI view objects
        mLatLng = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lat_lng);
        mLatLng.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        mAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
        mActivityIndicator = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.address_progress);
        mConnectionState = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_connection_state);
        tvStartUpdates = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.start_updates);
        tvStopUpdates = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stop_updates);
        showHideCallayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.showHideCalLayout);
        showHideButlayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.showHideButLayout);

        btShowHide=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btShowHide);
        btShowHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(btShowHide.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("-")){
            showHideButlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            showHideCallayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            btShowHide.setText("+");
                }else if(btShowHide.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("+")){
                    showHideButlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    showHideCallayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btShowHide.setText("-");

                }
            }
        });

        showHideButlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        showHideCallayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        tvStartUpdates.setEnabled(true);
        tvStopUpdates.setEnabled(false);

        mConnectionState.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mConnectionStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_connection_status);
        mConnectionStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        distancekmm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_lat_lng);
        tvTotalFaree = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotalFareee);
        tvBaseFare = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvbaseFare);
            Toast.makeText(StartMeterActivity.this, "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           gps = new GPSTracker(StartMeterActivity.this);
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){


        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

        mLocationRequest.setInterval(LocationUtils.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Use high accuracy
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(LocationUtils.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Note that location updates are off until the user turns them on
        mUpdatesRequested = false;
          if (mGoogleMap == null) {
              SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

                // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
                mGoogleMap = fm.getMap();

                // check if map is created successfully or not
                if (mGoogleMap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }

//      while(mGoogleMap==null){
//
//      }
//      if(mGoogleMap!=null){
        mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //mGoogleMap.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 520);
        // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        //mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        //       LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        //          
        //          // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
              //      Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        //  
        //          // Getting the name of the best provider
            //        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        //  
        //          // Getting Current Location From GPS
                    Location l = getLocationn();
                    LatLng ll=new LatLng(l.getLatitude(), l.getLongitude());
//                  CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
//                  .target(ll)     // Sets the center of the map to Mountain View
//                  .zoom(14)                   // Sets the zoom
//                  //.bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
//                //  .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
//                  .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
//              mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                   mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 16));

        //          
        // Open Shared Preferences
        //   mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(LocationUtils.SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        // Get an editor
        //   mEditor = mPrefs.edit();

        /*
         * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to
         * handle callbacks.
         */
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);     }

        }       else{
//          // can't get location
//          // GPS or Network is not enabled
//          // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
//        
    }
        }}

    private void setRetainInstance(boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /*
     * Called when the Activity is no longer visible at all.
     * Stop updates and disconnect.
     */
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
            mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
        }
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
        // If the client is connected
        //        if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
        //            stopPeriodicUpdates();
        //        }
        //
        //        // After disconnect() is called, the client is considered "dead".
        //        mLocationClient.disconnect();

        super.onStop();
    }
    /*
     * Called when the Activity is going into the background.
     * Parts of the UI may be visible, but the Activity is inactive.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {

        // Save the current setting for updates
        // mEditor.putBoolean(LocationUtils.KEY_UPDATES_REQUESTED, mUpdatesRequested);
        //  mEditor.commit();

        super.onPause();
    }

    /*
     * Called when the Activity is restarted, even before it becomes visible.
     */
    @Override
    public void onStart() {

        super.onStart();

        /*
         * Connect the client. Don't re-start any requests here;
         * instead, wait for onResume()
         */
        mLocationClient.connect();
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));

    }
    /*
     * Called when the system detects that this Activity is now visible.
     */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mLocationClient.connect();
         int errorCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if(errorCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS && GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(errorCode)){
                Dialog d = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, 0);
                d.show();
            }
        // locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
        // If the app already has a setting for getting location updates, get it
        //        if (mPrefs.contains(LocationUtils.KEY_UPDATES_REQUESTED)) {
        //            mUpdatesRequested = mPrefs.getBoolean(LocationUtils.KEY_UPDATES_REQUESTED, false);
        //
        //        // Otherwise, turn off location updates until requested
        //        } else {
        //            mEditor.putBoolean(LocationUtils.KEY_UPDATES_REQUESTED, false);
        //            mEditor.commit();
        //        }

    }

    /*
     * Handle results returned to this Activity by other Activities started with
     * startActivityForResult(). In particular, the method onConnectionFailed() in
     * LocationUpdateRemover and LocationUpdateRequester may call startResolutionForResult() to
     * start an Activity that handles Google Play services problems. The result of this
     * call returns here, to onActivityResult.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        // Choose what to do based on the request code
        switch (requestCode) {

        // If the request code matches the code sent in onConnectionFailed
        case LocationUtils.CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST :

            switch (resultCode) {
            // If Google Play services resolved the problem
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                // Log the result
                Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG, getString(R.string.resolved));

                // Display the result
                mConnectionState.setText(R.string.connected);
                mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.resolved);
                mConnectionStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mConnectionState.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                break;

                // If any other result was returned by Google Play services
            default:
                // Log the result
                Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG, getString(R.string.no_resolution));

                // Display the result
                mConnectionState.setText(R.string.disconnected);
                mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.no_resolution);
                mConnectionStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mConnectionState.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                break;
            }

            // If any other request code was received
        default:
            // Report that this Activity received an unknown requestCode
            Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG,
                    getString(R.string.unknown_activity_request_code, requestCode));

            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verify that Google Play services is available before making a request.
     *
     * @return true if Google Play services is available, otherwise false
     */
    private boolean servicesConnected() {

        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode =
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            // In debug mode, log the status
            Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG, getString(R.string.play_services_available));

            // Continue
            return true;
            // Google Play services was not available for some reason
        } else {
            // Display an error dialog
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 0);
            if (dialog != null) {
                ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
                errorFragment.setDialog(dialog);
                errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), LocationUtils.APPTAG);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Invoked by the "Get Location" button.
     *
     * Calls getLastLocation() to get the current location
     *
     * @param v The view object associated with this method, in this case a Button.
     */
    public void getLocation(View v) {

        // If Google Play Services is available
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WaitingActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
    }

    /**
     * Invoked by the "Get Address" button.
     * Get the address of the current location, using reverse geocoding. This only works if
     * a geocoding service is available.
     *
     * @param v The view object associated with this method, in this case a Button.
     */
    // For Eclipse with ADT, suppress warnings about Geocoder.isPresent()
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void getAddress(View v) {

        // In Gingerbread and later, use Geocoder.isPresent() to see if a geocoder is available.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD && !Geocoder.isPresent()) {
            // No geocoder is present. Issue an error message
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.no_geocoder_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if (servicesConnected()) {

            // Get the current location
            Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();

            // Turn the indefinite activity indicator on
            mActivityIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Start the background task
            (new StartMeterActivity.GetAddressTask(this)).execute(currentLocation);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Invoked by the "Start Updates" button
     * Sends a request to start location updates
     *
     * @param v The view object associated with this method, in this case a Button.
     */
    public void startUpdates(View v) {

        mUpdatesRequested = true;
//      tvBaseFare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//      tvTotalFare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (servicesConnected()) {
            startPeriodicUpdates();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Invoked by the "Stop Updates" button
     * Sends a request to remove location updates
     * request them.
     *
     * @param v The view object associated with this method, in this case a Button.
     */
    public void stopUpdates(View v) {
        mUpdatesRequested = false;

        if (servicesConnected()) {
            stopPeriodicUpdates();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
     * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
     * request the current location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.connected);
        mConnectionStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //  prevLocation = getLocation(mLocationClient);
        if (mUpdatesRequested) {
            startPeriodicUpdates();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
     * location client drops because of an error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.disconnected);
        mConnectionStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the attempt to
     * Location Services fails.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {

                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(
                        this,
                        LocationUtils.CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */

            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

            // If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the user with the error.
            showErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Report location updates to the UI.
     *
     * @param location The updated location.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        changedLocation=location;
       // LatLng endPosition = new LatLng(changedLocation.getLatitude(), changedLocation.getLongitude());


        mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.location_updated);


        // In the UI, set the latitude and longitude to the value received
//      if (marker != null) {
//          marker.remove();
//      }
        // Report to the UI that the location was updated
        mConnectionStatus.setText(R.string.location_updated);
        mConnectionStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mConnectionState.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        // In the UI, set the latitude and longitude to the value received

        double lat =  location.getLatitude();

        double lng = location.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Location " + lat+","+lng,
                1000).show();
        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(coordinate));
        //mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));


        //mLatLng.setText(lat+"    "+lng);
        //   mLatLng.setText(df.format(lat)+"        " +df.format(lng));

        //   Toast.makeText(this, "Location " + coordinate.latitude+","+coordinate.longitude,1000).show();

        //      mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(coordinate));
        //      mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));

        rectOptions.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        this.savePolyline=rectOptions;

        mGoogleMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code .

Comment: Your code not visible